# straight_join in JPA or HIBERNATE

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

How to use `select straight_join ... from ...`  in hibernate/jpa?

Comment: what is "straight_join" ? have you read a JPA document defining JPQL ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no straight_join for JPQL/JPA.

You will need to use it in NativeQuery.

entityManager.createNativeQuery(...);

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible in the Hibernate 5.2.12 and MySQL version 8 using optimizer hint JOIN_FIXED_ORDER (the same effect as STRAIGHT_JOIN)
More information available under the links:

Jira ticket:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11906

Hibernate code change that allows this:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/72506a6eacc367297a3205f6e1fec7ccbc153799

Documentation for MySQL Optimizer hints:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html