# Hibernate failing to parse native query containing STRAIGHT_JOIN keyword

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a native sql query used inside @Formula annotation in a hibernate entity, but Hibernate is failing to parse it, and throws a syntax error exception.
The entity/query is something similar to the following:

```
@Table(name="table2")
public class Table2{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Formula("(SELECT MAX(table1.col1) from table1 STRAIGHT_JOIN table2 t ON"   
     + "(table1.col2 = t.col2) INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON (t3.col1 = t.col1) 
    WHERE t3.col2 = 1)")
    private Integer code;

    @Column
    private Type type;
    ....
    //getters and setters
    ....
}
```

On looking at the mysql query logs, following is the actual query being executed:

```
 select table2x0_.id, table2x0_.type, (SELECT MAX(table1.col1) from table1  
 STRAIGHT_JOIN table2x0_.table2 table2x0_.t ON (table1.col2 = t.col2) INNER JOIN  
 table3 AS t3 ON (t3.col1 = t.col1) WHERE t3.col2 = 1) as formula1_ from table2  
 table2x0_ where table2x0_.type in (0,1,2);
```

It appears that hibernate is having issues with the STRAIGHT_JOIN keyword. Instead of STRAIGHT_JOIN table2 t, the query is being written as STRAIGHT_JOIN table2x0_.table2 table2x0_.t, i.e., it is prefixing the outer query's table alias.

If I replace STRAIGHT_JOIN with INNER JOIN, the query works fine. But I need to use STRAIGHT_JOIN for my use case.

Can someone please help with how to resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782991/straight-join-in-jpa-or-hibernate

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try some other way.